# How to create 'intelligent' snippet for VScode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'm extending the functionality of VSCode for C++.
Can I create this snippet?
*Before snippet:*
(Cursor is marked by `|`)

```cpp
stuff* arr;
// ...
arr = |
```

*After snippet*

```cpp
stuff* arr;
// ...
arr = new stuff; // <-- `stuff` is inserted automatically 
                 //             according to value type
```

Probably the solution is in creating a script that will find the declaration of `arr`. But how to do it?

Comment: for this you must parse the source code and do this over multiple files because it most likely is in a header file. Writing a full C++ parser is quite some work....

Comment: what happens the next time you type `arr = `, now you have to undo your snippet. The parsing really gets fun when you allow `decltype`.